# How to find whether a column values are starting with letter access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like

```
  Name       Description    EID        Basecode        
  -----      -----------    ----       ---------
  name1      ssdad          1001       S2378797     
  name2      gfd            1002       S1164478     
  name3      gfdsffsdf      1003       R1165778     
  name4      ssdad          1004       M0007867     
  name5      gfd            1005       N7765111     
  name6      gfdsffsdf      1006       W5464111     
  name5      gfd            1005       N7765111     
  name6      gfdsffsdf      1006       A4000011 
  name6      gfdsffsdf      1006       W5464111     
  name10     ssdad          1001       2378797     
  name21     gfd            1002       1164478  
  name17     ssdad          1001       765
  name81     gfd            1002       1167
```

How to retrieve rows, only if columns data starts with any letter other than **W** and **N** in **Basecode** column.

To retrieve like

```
  Name       Description    EID        Basecode  
  -----      -----------    ----       ---------      
  name1      ssdad          1001       S2378797     
  name2      gfd            1002       S1164478     
  name3      gfdsffsdf      1003       R1165778     
  name4      ssdad          1004       M0007867     
  name6      gfdsffsdf      1006       A4000011
```

Comment: This is very basic SQL. Look up Like clause in MS Access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Left and In as another approach, for example:

```
SELECT t.Name, t.Description, t.EID, t.Basecode
FROM TheTable AS t
WHERE Not IsNumeric(Left(t.Basecode,1)) AND Left(t.Basecode,1) Not In ("W","N")
```

Comment: As it was pointed out to me, OP also wants to exclude entries beginning with a digit. Glad we have someone more familiar with the Access dialect of SQL than I am though!

Comment: @RobP I was working on that as an afterthought even as you spoke :)

Answer (score 1):

For a query run from within the Access application itself you could use something like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM YourTableName 
WHERE Basecode LIKE '[a-m]*' OR Basecode LIKE '[o-v]*' OR Basecode LIKE '[x-z]*'
```

Edit: As HansUp points out, the above can be condensed to

```sql
SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE Basecode LIKE '[a-mo-vx-z]*'
```

Comment: Access will let you combine those character ranges into one pattern string: `WHERE Basecode LIKE '[a-mo-vx-z]*'`

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE NOT SUBSTRING(Basecode,1,1) IN ('W', 'N')` is valid for MySQL and I think it's the same for Access. A good SQL tutorial would be your friend and worth a day or two of study. Maybe start with http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/introduction-to-access-sql-HA010341468.aspx

EDIT: Good comment! To also exclude things beginning with numbers, REGEXP would be more readable (though not faster, probably, if that matters.) I'll leave that as an exercise but you'd want WHERE NOT LIKE REGEXP(... using an anchor for searching start of string, then a character group of W, N, or any digit. This site is a great learning tool: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

EDIT2: Another solution that works in MySQL and I think is fairly standard would be

```
SELECT * FROM table 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING(Basecode,1,1), 'W, N, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9') = 0
```

if ms-access supports it.

Comment: Could also do ...`WHERE NOT Basecode LIKE 'W%' AND NOT Basecode LIKE 'N%'`

Comment: Sample output suggests that values beginning with a numeric digit should be omitted as well.

Comment: Thanks, good point. Edited to reflect an approach to handle that without the verbose AND NOT... repetition for 0 through 9

Comment: The above way is a performance killer if you are dealing with huge table. I like the one in the comment section - `WHERE NOT Basecode LIKE 'W%' AND NOT Basecode LIKE 'N%'` - better.

Comment: all depends on the size of the table... you are right there's a big difference in performance but if it's a single user system with 1,000 rows, for example, it just doesn't matter!

Comment: I think my favorite might be `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(SUBSTRING(Basecode,1,1), 'W, N, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9') = 0` if ms-access supports it.

Comment: SQL is a generic tag, the particular type requested is MS Access. I am afraid that none of this will work in MS Access.

Answer (score 0):

So, if you wanted to get queries for cols where starts with W or N it would be like this:

`SELECT * FROM YourTableName WHERE Basecode LIKE 'W*' OR Basecode LIKE 'N*'`

Comment: That's not what the Question asks for though.